# Second, Minute, Hour, Date, Weekly, and Monthly based regression and correlation analysis

Tags: date, time, regression, correlation, dayofweek

I have a time and date-based dataset. I need to do second-, minute-, hour-, date-, and weekly-based correlation and regression analysis.

The variables I have are MeasTime, RawCH4, RawH2, ConveCH4, and ConvH2. So I need to do second, minute-, hour-, date-, and weekly-based correlation and regression of RawCH4 and ConveCH4. When run the data bydfr=lm(RawCH4~ConveCH4, df) I got second-based regression and correlation. But I need to see the regression and correlation of these variables by minutes, hours, and dates. So how do I categorize/subset my dataset and get the regression and correlation analysis on a minute-, hour-, date-, and weekly-based basis? I can subset the dataset by time and date and do the correlation and regression analysis for each minute, hour, date, and time, but this method takes a long time. So, how can I get the result time- and date-based?

```
   MeasTime         RawCH4 RawH2 ConvCH4 ConvH2
   <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1/12/2022 0:0000   1233   436    1233    436
 2 1/12/2022 0:0001   1225   436    1225    436
 3 1/12/2022 0:0002   1233   436    1233    436
 4 1/12/2022 0:0003   1233   436    1233    436
 5 1/12/2022 0:0004   1229   435    1229    435
 6 1/12/2022 0:0005   1233   435    1233    435
 7 1/12/2022 0:0006   1232   434    1232    434
 8 1/12/2022 0:0007   1229   436    1229    436
 9 1/12/2022 0:0008   1237   436    1237    436
10 1/12/2022 0:0009   1233   436    1233    436
```

## … with 3,864,059 more rows

Comment: How is the time represented? I suppose the `0.0000` is the time of day? Which time of day does for example `0.0007` signify? Also which tool and/or scripting language are you using for your analysis?

Comment: Thank you, Ole. The time is the time of the day and the sensor record data for each second. 00:00:00, 00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:00:03................................

Comment: So 12 noon (43 200 seconds after midnight) would be given as 4.3200? Or as 12:0000? Or ...?

Comment: Its given 43200.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I recommend that you add the clarification to the question itself so other users see it too. I believe that many don’t get around to reading the comments. Remember to add your tool and/or language too.